# Cambiar imagen al recargar archivo

Tags: javascript

EL siguiente código sencillo al hacer clic en la bandera de España cambia por la de Portugal, como hago para que al recargar el documento me salga la bandera de Portugal y no la de España

```js
function image() {

var image = document.getElementById('esp');

image.src= "https://i.imgur.com/dgEXyHG.png"
         
}
```

```html
<img id="esp" onclick="image();"  src="https://i.imgur.com/wXQPLGv.png" width="48" 

height="48"  style="margin:-8px 0px 0px 42px;"/>
```

Comment: Usas localstorage y alternas entre una imagen y otra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto lo puedes hacer por medio de `localStorage`:

**HTML:**

```
<img id="esp" onclick="image();" src="" width="48" height="48" style="margin:-8px 0px 0px 42px;"/>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
let img        = document.getElementById("esp");
const espana   = "https://i.imgur.com/wXQPLGv.png";
const portugal = "https://i.imgur.com/dgEXyHG.png";
let actual     = localStorage.getItem("actual");
// aquí defines una bandera por defecto para cuando no exista una guardada.
// en este caso yo puse españa por defecto.
img.src        = (actual != null) ? actual : espana; 

function image() {
    img.src = (img.src == espana) ? portugal : espana;
    localStorage.setItem("actual", img.src);
}
```

Declaras tus variables principales que son tus **2 imágenes** y tu etiqueta **img** que mantienes con un **src** vacío.

Al momento de cargar tu página al **img.src** le asignara uno en caso de que exista uno guardado, en caso contrario pondrá uno establecido por defecto. En la función `image()` simplemente verificamos si el **src** es igual a España asignamos Portugal y en caso contrario asignamos España.

**Nota:** No agrego la ejecución aquí, ya que Stack Overflow corre **JsFiddle** en Sandbox y no permite la ejecución de `localStorage`.